# Как совместить КОД с ГУИ

Tags: python, tkinter

Пытался сделать по-разному, но в ГУИ мой код не выводился.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title('ШРЕК.exe')
root.geometry('600x400')
button = Button(root, text='press START', font=40, command=test)
button.pack(side=BOTTOM, pady=50)

CAT_1 = Label(root, text='Первый кот\n-', font=35)
CAT_1.pack(pady=(50,0))
CAT_2 = Label(root, text="Второй кот\n-",font=35)
CAT_2.pack(pady=(10,0))
root.mainloop()
```

---

```
    class Cat:
        name = None
        age = None
        isHappy = None

        def set_data(self, name, age, isHappy):
            self.name = name
            self.age = age
            self.isHappy = isHappy

        def get_data(self):
            print(self.name,'-', 'Возраст:', self.age, self.isHappy)

name1 = input('Имя первого кота: ')
name2 = input('Имя второго кота: ')
age1 = input('Возраст первого кота: ')
age2 = input('Возраст второго кота: ')
happy1 = input(name1+ ' счастлив или не счастлив: ')
happy2 = input(name2+ ' счастлив или не счастлив: ')

print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')

cat1 = Cat()
cat1.set_data(name1 , age1 ,happy1)

cat2 = Cat()
cat2.set_data(name2,age2,happy2)

cat1.get_data()
cat2.get_data()
```

Comment: Ничего не понял. Где КОД, где ГУИ???

Comment: вместо инпутов сделайте текстовые поля entry. а вместо принтов label /ну и разместите всё как желаете

Answer (score 0):

заместо input используйте entry

```
txt = Entry(root) #сам текстовый виджет
res = format(txt.get()) #получаем написанный текст
```

заместо print используйте текст от канвас

```
canvas = Canvas(root, width=ширина, height=высота)
canvas.pack()
kot1_info = canvas.create_text(width=x,height=y, text="текст", fill="цвет") #x и y - координаты
```

если надо будет менять содержимое текста

```
canvas.itemconfig(kot1_info, text="новый текст")
```